# How to set vim filetype when editing nginx config files

Tags: ubuntu, vim

When I open vim for a file like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, syntax highlighting works fine. But then if I create my own file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp`, vim does not highlight its syntax. I have to do `:setf conf` every time.

Is there anything I can put in `~/.vimrc` to tell vim "if you don't know which syntax to use, just use `conf`" ?

A `.vimrc` template for a vim noob is also welcome. I'm not using it as an IDE, I use vim mostly for config files only.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 12, in case it matters.

Comment: I changed your title to more accurately reflect what you are trying to do and re-asked the question here, since this can be useful in the general case: http://serverfault.com/a/390801/2101

Comment: @MikeyB I didn't know or care about 'filetypes', as far as I knew vim could have been doing the syntax highlighting just by looking at the code and guessing the language. And the main part of the problem was that I wanted it to be 'by default'. I already knew how to 'set the language/filetype when editing'. Also, whether it is for nginx or anything else, is irrelevant. Do as you want, I never understood why serverfault people decide to close or edit questions (for SEO maybe?). Unless grammatically incorrect, the original title reflected my problem.

Comment: possibly interesting: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1886 (I use it and it's pretty nice, add a `# vim:syn=nginx` at the bottom of the configs)

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: the reason I edited it was that your accepted answer indicates "Oh, I really was trying to do that." Now future visitors will be able to search for 'default vim filetype' or 'default vim syntax' and get the correct answer for that instead of getting frustrated since the accepted answer doesn't say how to accomplish the title of the question. Plus, now you also know how to set the default filetype :)

Comment: @MikeyB The new title doesn't even use the word 'default'. The original one did.

Comment: `:se ft=conf` for having the comments at least highlighted.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following line in `~/.vimrc` should do this.

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /etc/nginx/sites-*/* setfiletype conf
```

Comment: slight correction autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /etc/nginx/sites-*/* setfiletype conf

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1886 provides better syntax highlighting than the `conf` filetype. If you use Vundle, try `Plugin 'vim-scripts/nginx.vim'`.

Comment: For all .conf files, I put the command as this: `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.conf setfiletype conf`

Answer (score 36):

There's actually an Nginx file type defined in [the official Nginx repository](https://github.com/nginx/nginx) in the [contrib/vim](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/master/contrib/vim) directory.  It provides better syntax highlighting than *conf*.

To use it, copy [the detection lines](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/contrib/vim/ftdetect/nginx.vim) to your *.vimrc* (and tweak as desired):

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.nginx set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile */etc/nginx/* set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile */usr/local/nginx/conf/* set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile nginx.conf set ft=nginx
```

Then copy [nginx.vim](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/contrib/vim/syntax/nginx.vim) to your *~/.vim/syntax* directory.

All Nginx files following the above rules should now be highlighted.

If you'd like the indenting as well, you can also copy [the file from the indent directory](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/contrib/vim/indent/nginx.vim) into your *.vimrc*.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to get vim filetype you want is to specify it at the top of the file via a modeline. In this case, place the following comment in the first 5 lines of the file

```
#       vim: set syntax=nginx ft=nginx
```

More information on filetype and modeline is available here
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline

Comment: This doesn't seem easier than the autoconfiguration provided by the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer assumes the filename will match an absolute path glob and that you have control of the .vimrc. Neither may be true, e.g. if you're working in a git repo on files pushed out via CICD pipeline or logging in via shared break-glass account. Specifying the filetype selection within the file itself solves those cases.

Answer (score 1):

No need to edit `vimrc` for that. Just take `contrib/vim` files from `nginx` source tree and place them into `$HOME/.vim` so that tree should be like that:

```
/home/ubuntu/.vim
├── ftdetect
│   └── nginx.vim
├── ftplugin
│   └── nginx.vim
├── indent
│   └── nginx.vim
└── syntax
    └── nginx.vim
```

Then whenever you open `nginx.conf` `ft` gets detected and highlight gets applied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on a small Debian install, the relevant files already existed (possibly for the default `vim.tiny`) but weren't sourced in regular `vim`. It was easily fixed with this:

```bash
for d in ftdetect ftplugin indent syntax; do
    sudo mkdir /var/lib/vim/addons/$d
    sudo ln -s /usr/share/vim/addons/$d/nginx.vim /var/lib/vim/addons/$d/nginx.vim
done
```