# Setting a default vim filetype for syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

How do I tell vim to automatically use a particular filetype (usually for syntax highlighting) when none is detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to the end of your `~/.vimrc` (change `conf` to whichever filetype you would like as default):

```
if &filetype==""
  setfiletype conf
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

From within vim:

```
 :runtime! syntax/c.vim
```

Comment: To be clear, this answer is for setting a filetype automatically when none is detected. This just sets the syntax to a C file at runtime.

Comment: @MikeyB See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666551/vim-default-syntax-for-files-with-no-extension - it says e.g. `au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | set syntax=html | endif`.